# decodeFunctionResult: get output from a transaction receipt using ethers (js). maybe bug in ethers v5

Tags: transactions, decode, solidity, smartcontracts, ethers.js

The challenge is to extract an output `uint256` from a receipt tx of a public smart contract using ethers in a js script that interacts with a smart contract.

Consider the following very simple `contract1.sol`. We are gonna play with the variable `_val_1`, and the function `fun_sum256`.

```js
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
contract Contract1  {

  string public _str_1;
  uint256 public _val_1;

  constructor(string memory str_in1, uint256 in_val_1 ) {
    _str_1 = str_in1;
    _val_1 = in_val_1;
  } //endconstructor

  function get_str() external view returns (string memory) {
    return _str_1;
  } //endfun get_str

  function set_str(string memory str_in1) external returns (string memory) {
    _str_1 = str_in1;
    return _str_1;
  } //endfun set_str

  function fun_sum256(uint256 in_val_2) public returns (uint256) {
    _val_1 += in_val_2;
    return _val_1;
  } //endfun sum256

} //endcon
```

As observed in `ethers`, the procedure for decoding the `tx_receipt.data` requires the usage of an interface,

```js
let value = contract.interface.decodeFunctionResult(fragment, result);
```

where `fragment` is the `"fun_sum256"` corresponding function fragment, and result, is the data of the tx-receipt (properly mined and waited). The function fragment can also be directly called in the following way, `<yourDeployedContract>.interface.functions["fun_sum256(uint256)"]`.

It simply does not work, at least for me. I can extract the other string argument `_str_1`, but not the `uint` types. But on the contrary, on remix-ide, it does. If I init the `_val_1` with value 1 in constructor, and then I invoke the `fun_uint256` public function with an input of 2, it successfully works on remix, performing 1+2=3, to see the `decoded output "0: uint256: 3"`. And indeed, from my js script that interacts with the contract I can foresee the value in the txdata, the last cypher:
`0x78081f400000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000003`

But ethers v5 simply seems incapable of extracting that "3".

Can anyone provide a very simple example with a `simple.sol` and the corresponding `simple.js` to interact with, that works with ethers library in js?

Answer (score 1):

Not possible by design.

A **transaction** return value is only available onchain, as a result of an internal transaction.

```
contract A {
    // mind the missing `view` keyword, suggesting a transaction
    function getBValue() external returns (uint256) {
        uint256 BValue = B(address(0x123)).getValue();
        // `BValue` is available onchain, but not offchain
        return BValue;
    }
}

contract B {
    // mind the missing `view` keyword, suggesting a transaction
    function getValue() external returns (uint256) {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

So when you execute `A`.`getBValue()`, the EVM also performs an internal transaction to `B`.`getValue()`. But the value is not available outside of this scope (e.g. in the transaction receipt).

---

On the other hand, a **call** return value is availabe both onchain and offchain.

```
contract A {
    // mind the existing `view` keyword, suggesting a call
    function getBValue() external view returns (uint256) {
        uint256 BValue = B(address(0x123)).getValue();
        // `BValue` is available both onchain and offchain
        return BValue;
    }
}

contract B {
    // mind the existing `view` keyword, suggesting a call
    function getValue() external view returns (uint256) {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

When you make a **call** to `A`.`getBValue()`, you are able to get the value offchain.

---

**Suggestion:** In this case, you can mark the `fun_sum256()` function as `view` ([docs](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.10/contracts.html#view-functions)), which will make the `ethers` library to perform a **call** instead of a **transaction**, so that the returned value will be available in your JS code.

Comment: Thank you for the response. However it generates more doubts on me, if I kindly may ask,
1) Then, what is the purpose of `decodeFunctionResults`? could you provide a simple example of usage to decode the result of a function? (I assume that's why it is called decode-function-result)
2) Why Remix-ide is able to read the response properly?
3) If I set `view` then the function cannot modify the `state` (there is no modification data and no transactions, so I cannot modify the internal variable `_var_1`). Thank you.

Comment: I respond myself to the 3 answers, thanks to your great knowledge and ricmoo user I understand that it's not possible up to now to get the output of a non-view function, and that remix is only able bc of it's internal rpc simulated environment (either ganache, etc). Maybe it is even not intented to, a design criterium, not to access to results of state functions.

Comment: My apologies. I just realize I forgot to score positively your response. I do it now.